# Has the method annotations in R(NLP package) been deprecated or replaced?

Tags: r, opennlp, rjava, magrittr

I am following this article  https://mylearnmachinelearning.com/category/linear-regression/ to create a Named Entity Extractor. Like required, I have installed all the `openNLP`, `NLP`, `rJava`, `magrittr` and `openNLPmodels.en` packages. All has gone to plan except when using this function **`annotations`**.:

```
 # Extract entities from an AnnotatedPlainTextDocument
     entities <- function(doc, kind) {
     s <- doc$content
     a <- annotations(doc)[[1]] #Point of error
     if(hasArg(kind)) {
         k <- sapply(a$features, `[[`, "kind")
         s[a[k == kind]]
     } else {
         s[a[a$type == "entity"]]
     }
 }
```

by using this:

`entities(text_doc, kind = "person")`.

The thing is even the intellisense in RStudio does not seem to know any function **`annotations`**. It show `annotation`,`annotate` and `annotations_in_spans` and what not but there is no `annotations`.

There is even a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lpQludiI-0&list=PL2kLU7a2SN4WDHo0Vp68LcTGp6L26EYs8&index=2&t=0s) which demonstrates the same. Strangely he is able to use `annotations` there.

Package versions:

1. openNLP: v0.2-6
2. openNLPmodels.en: v1.5-1
3. rJava - v0.9-9
4. magrittr - v1.5
5. NLP - v0.2-0

Comment: +1 for instantly returning me to my youth by using the word *intellisense* - the good old Visual Basic and Excel period of my life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `annotations` method was associated with objects of type `AnnotatedPlainTextDocument` in earlier versions of the `NLP` package.

[Here is the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NLP/versions/0.1-11/topics/AnnotatedPlainTextDocument) for version 0.1-11.

[The latest NLP version](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NLP/versions/0.2-0) is 0.2-0.

[The method for AnnotatedPlainTextDocument](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NLP/versions/0.2-0/topics/AnnotatedPlainTextDocument) is now called `annotation` (no 's' at the end). From the documentation it seems the main difference is that it returns an `Annotation` object, not a list of `Annotation` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The function `annotations` is in a lot of packages, please see here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=annotations

Albeit probably not the best way, if you are looking for a specific function without knowing which package the function belongs to, this site may help you find such a package.

Comment: There is no OpenSNP package. You are thinking of `rsnps`, which provides access to OpenSNP data. And that package is for the analysis of genetic data, not related to NLP.

Comment: I stand corrected and updated the answer. Where a package was meant for specifically does not always matter. My answer is more broad and can be used used to handle any of the kind of questions like "in which package can I find this function". Hope it serves others better than it did to you.

Comment: You are correct that the rdocumentation site is a great resource to search for functions. However, given that the original question refers to NLP and the functions come from that package, it's not helpful to point them to an irrelevant package. Remove the reference to `rsnps` and you may find that the annoying down-vote goes away :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
# Extract entities from an AnnotatedPlainTextDocument
         entities <- function(doc, kind) {
         s <- doc$content
         a <- annotation(doc)
         if(hasArg(kind)) {
             k <- sapply(a$features, `[[`, "kind")
             s[a[k == kind]]
         } else {
             s[a[a$type == "entity"]]
         }
     }
```

Comment: I installed the coreNLP from Stanford University, added it to the list of required libraries, and removed the [[1]] that was listed after the annotation(doc) and it ran successfully.